# Need to filter responses by grade, taking out the "false" and n/a" responses

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to filter out the responses on so that for column b and l, the only names left are those of the students that meet the criteria, essentially getting rid of the false and na's in the other cells.

Any help would be appreciated. I attached a picture so you can see the formula I used.

[image: Sheets with temp data]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IFERROR(IF('Form Responses 1'!$C3="4th", 'Form Responses 1'!$B3, ))
```

the comma after B3 will remove `FALSE`es and `IFEEROR` will remove `#N/A` errors